# background image's fadeInOut transitions produces weird effect in white all the texts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, opacity

Well this problem is kind of weird,

I have a website where the background image changes with a fadeIn/Out transition

Video: http://www.screenr.com/ZCvs

Web in action: http://toniweb.us/gm

The markup:

```
        <div class="fondo" onclick="descargar(2,500);descargar(1,500);"></div>
        <div id="headerimgs">
            <div id="headerimg1" class="headerimg"></div>
            <div id="headerimg2" class="headerimg"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Inicio Cabecera -->
```

CSS:

```
.headerimg { 
    background-position: center top; background-repeat: no-repeat; width:100%;position:absolute;height:100%;cursor:pointer; 
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;

}
.headerimg img{ 
    min-width:100%; width:100%; height:100%;
}

    .fondo{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Javascript:

```
/*Gestion de pase de imágenes de fondo*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    /*controla la velocidad de la animación*/
    var slideshowSpeed = 3000;
    var transitionSpeed = 2000;
    var timeoutSpeed = 500;

    /*No tocar*/
    var interval;
    var activeContainer = 1;    
    var currentImg = 0;
    var animating = false;
    var navigate = function(direction) {
        // Si ya estamos navegando, entonces no hacemos nada!
        if(animating) {
            return;
        }
        currentImg++;
        if(currentImg == photos.length + 1) {
            currentImg = 1;
        }
        // Tenemos dos, uno en el que tenemos la imagen que se ve y otro d?nde tenemos la imagen siguiente
        var currentContainer = activeContainer;
        // Esto puedo optimizarlo con la funci?n modulo, y cambiar 1 y 2 por 0 y 1-> active = mod2(active + 1)
        if(activeContainer == 1) {
            activeContainer = 2;
        } else {
            activeContainer = 1;
        }
        // hay que decrementar el ?ndice porque empieza por cero
        cargarImagen(photos[currentImg - 1], currentContainer, activeContainer);
    };
    var currentZindex = -1;
    var cargarImagen = function(photoObject, currentContainer, activeContainer) {
        animating = true;
        // Nos aseguramos que el nuevo contenedor está siempre dentro del cajon
        currentZindex--;
        //if(currentZindex < 0) currentZindex=1;
        // Actualizar la imagen
        $("#headerimg" + activeContainer).css({
            "background-image" : "url(" + photoObject + ")",
            "display" : "block",
            "z-index" : currentZindex
        });
        // FadeOut antigua
        // Cuando la transición se ha completado, mostramos el header 
        $("#headerimg" + currentContainer).fadeOut(transitionSpeed,function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#headertxt").css({"display" : "block"});
                animating = false;
            }, timeoutSpeed);
        });
    };
    //ver la primera
     navigate("next");
    //iniciar temporizador que mostrará las siguientes



    interval = setInterval(function() {
        navigate("next");
    }, slideshowSpeed);

});
```

there is also an overlay div (class fondo) (height and width 100%) so i can dectect when the background has been clicked (i can not use directly the background div because the transition makes it have negative z-index)

the problem is that this transition produces a weird effect in all white texts

any idea what am i missing?

Comment: in what browsers? works fine in chrome

Comment: interesting. true! but in firefox it is happening

Comment: works also fine in firfox 8, IE8 and glitchy but ok in safari. Not related but: My safari was decent sized and it showed the no-mobile sign. Something to consider!

Comment: about the no mobile is a temporal joke to my boss :$

Comment: Just noticed you have a pixel or two too much on your site height, making so that a scroll is added needlessly.

Comment: I am not seeing this in Firefox 8.0 with Win 7 (it appears to be showing the Arial font, not your "Cabin" font that you list first.

Comment: I can say that its coming along. The last time I saw a quesiton of yours the site for just the structure

Comment: Also works fine in all my browsers.

Comment: I can corroborate that... works fine for me in any browser/combination I can try.  Could you tell us exactly what OS and browser you see this effect in?

Comment: Windows 7.  I'm getting a repro on Firefox 4.0 and 8.0.1, though the effect is subtle.  Chrome 16.0.912.63 beta-m does not have the issue.

Comment: I don't know for sure (would have to dig into your layout a lot more) but my first guess is that there is some sort of overlay that handles some part of the fadeout effect who's z-index is somehow ending up in front of the buttons.  I see you have a `z-index 10 !important` as part of your code.  Maybe applying a different z-index to the buttons panel to ensure it ends up always on top might help?

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham tried that.. will play a bit more with it

Comment: Try removing: `-moz-transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;` (line 97 css.css). I'd also make the margins exact pixels to help the browser render the custom fonts. `margin: auto 8%;` to `margin: auto 0px;`

Comment: It's called 'cancel' not 'cancell' in 'Make or cancell a reservation'

Comment: Maybe it's with the webfont. Try with just the Arial

Comment: guys thanks all for your help but i didn't really get it fixed so i decided to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607996/custom-background-fadeinout-gallery in case you are still interested in this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what caused the glitches on your computer, I can't reproduce it: I test using IE7,8,9, latest Chrome and Firefox on Windows 7. Please provide us with more information about your setup. Did you visit a 3d-enabled website before testing your own site? It seems like a graphics-card bug. Did you use the latest browser and graphics card drivers?

On a side note, something you might want to consider is making your fade animation easier: it stutters a bit in Chrome after initial load.

The easiest animation that can do this thing is a window.setInterval with the following code executing:

```
function(){
    var container = $('#headerimgs');
    var current = container.children('div:visible:first');
    var next = (current.next().length > 1) ? current.next() : container.children('div:visible');

    current.fadeOut(300);
    next.fadeIn(300);
}
```

Fiddle a bit with the durations to get the exact effect you want. Note, you'll need to position the .headerimg divs absolutely, so they overlap completely.

Comment: same, I can't see any problems. FF8 on OSX

Comment: This isn't my bug or site (I'm just commenting), but I can repro it.  Not in Chrome, but in multiple versions of FF.  Some people can repro it, so *something* is going on.  Telling clients to update their video drivers to visit your website isn't going to be an option :)  It has now reproed on multiple machines, so some clients will see it.  If it is related to how certain stacks of effects end up being rendered on some drivers, there hopefully should be a way to work around it...

Comment: hi i wanted to try your implementation daan but i can't see where do you set the image paths there ?

Comment: could you maybe give me a hint? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607996/custom-background-fadeinout-gallery

Answer (score 1):

***Trace your fade in / out start and ending...***

Chances are it might be an asyncronous error, in which more then one fade in / out is occurring or is left occurring at the same time, that may have been set incorrectly...

This is **more of a conjuncture then an answer**, however these flickering issues with fadeIn / out, tend to boil down to this (from experience, 90+% of the time).

Also check if you have any mouseover / mouseenter CSS properties / events.

Apologies that i cant trace it myself: as i cant seem to repro the error either.

Random : Chrome sometimes do not show these asyncronous errors, due to it being too fast. The error can end up being a frame (or none), that is effectively invisible to the eye. Likewise for really fast computers.

Comment: thank for your answer but i am not sure if i understood whats your advice

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet, add a `console.log('fadingIn start');` prior to each trace, and add an ending function with `console.log('fadingIn complete');` for both in/out.