# custom background fadeInOut gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, background, rotation

Because of this  [background image's fadeInOut transitions produces weird effect in white all the texts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488364/background-images-fadeinout-transitions-produces-weird-effect-in-white-all-the) i decided to program my own custom image rotator with fadeinout effect

```
var intervalo;
var i= 0;
var photos = [
    "http://toniweb.us/gm/img/galeria/fondo1.jpg",
                "http://toniweb.us/gm/img/galeria/fondo2.jpg",
                "http://toniweb.us/gm/img/galeria/fondo3.jpg",
                "http://toniweb.us/gm/img/galeria/fondo4.jpg"
];

function rotarFondo(){
    var container = $('#headerimgs');
    var current = container.children('div:visible:first');
    var imgSrc = photos[i];
    i++;
    if(i == photos.length)
         i = 0;

    console.log(imgSrc);
    var next = (current.next().length > 1) ? current.next() : container.children('div:visible');
    current.css('background',imgSrc);
    next.css('background',imgSrc);

    current.fadeOut(300);
    next.fadeIn(300);
}

function congelarFondo(){

}

$(document).ready(function(){
       if (intervalo )
        clearInterval(intervalo );
       intervalo = setInterval('rotarFondo()',1000);
});
```

the interval thing and the image calculation seems to work fine, but i don't know why the bgImgaes are actually not being applied,

Testing here for now http://jsfiddle.net/bE9Dq/27/

any idea??

Answer (score 1):

Well for starters it might save you some time and a few headaches to use one of these plugins:

- http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/
- http://bavotasan.com/2011/full-sizebackground-image-jquery-plugin/

(I've used them both)

First thing I've noticed with your code is you may need to set the background image as follows:

```
.css('background-image','url(' + imgSrc + ')');
```

Also notice on the second line ( the `next.`) you are still using `imgSrc` I think you mean to use `imgSrc1` instead?

Comment: ooooooooooooohps!!!!!! very obvious! thanks a lot, but there must be something else because still wont work

Comment: yey! http://jsfiddle.net/bE9Dq/27/ i will digg into those links and lets see thanks!